# Temporarily disable map interaction

Tags: openlayers

I want to add a screenshot functionality to my application: Zooming to a specific extent, rerendering the map and printing the viewport to a canvas.

Can I disable user interaction with the map for that period, i.e. for the timespan between clicking the screenshot button and finishing the print process, to prevent the map from changing its viewport/state during the process? Soimething like

```
map.disableInteraction();
printScreenshot().then(() => map.enableInteraction());
```

(Interaction not as in ol.interaction but rather any keyboard/mouse event that changes the map display)

Comment: `map.getInteractions().forEach((i) => {i.setActive(false);});` will disable all interactions

Comment: I did not mean "interaction" in this sense, I want to prevent any changes of the viewport made by the user.

Comment: The map interactions is how the user changes the viewport.  An alternative would be to disable all pointer events on the map `map.getTargetElement().style.pointerEvents = 'none';`

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I need to disable dragging when user has left mouse pressed